# Type definitions for peer packages in TypeScript monorepos: development vs production

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, typescript-typings, lerna, monorepo

I have a monorepo project that uses `yarn workspaces` and `lerna`; all its parts are written in TypeScript. The modules are located in subfolders like `packages/module-n` and each module has its own `package.json` with the following lines:

```
"main": "dist/index.js",
"types": "dist/index.ts",
```

The source code for each package is located in `packages/module-n/src/index.ts`, so nothing unusual.

When it comes to building from the command line or publishing, all works well – thanks to `tsconfig.json` and a `build` script in each package folder. However, when it comes to a day-to-day code editing in VSCode, things become not very convenient, even despite that I run `tsc --watch` all packages to keep linked dependencies in sync.

When I command-click on a definition that refers to a peer package, VSCode brings me to `packages/package-n/dist/index.d.ts` instead of `packages/package-n/src/index.ts` that I may be currently editing. Also, when I want to refactor something with `F2`, may `dist/index.d.ts` files get occasionally modified, which forces me to restart `build:watch` due to errors. The thing is that TypeScript sees manual tweaks in `**/dist/index.d.ts` and refuses to further update these files.

In order to overcome this inconvenience, I have written these two scripts in the root `package.json`, but I'm not a big fan of my own solution:

```
"use-dev-typings": "lerna exec \"replace --quiet dist\\/index\\.d\\.ts src/index.ts package.json\"",
"use-prod-typings": "lerna exec \"replace --quiet src\\/index\\.ts dist/index.d.ts package.json\""
```

Here is how I'm using them in the same root `package.json`:

```
"build": "yarn use-prod-typings && lerna run build",
"build:watch": "lerna run build; yarn use-dev-typings && lerna run --parallel build:watch",
```

The idea is that before I start editing files in VSCode and thus go for `yarn build:watch`, I patch all `packages/package-n/package.json` files by replacing `"types": "dist/index.d.ts"` with `"types": "src/index.ts"`. This fixes command+clicking and refactoring, which is great. When it comes to one-off building (e.g. before publishing), `"types"` revert to `"dist/index.d.ts"`.

I'm wondering if there is a better way to achieve what I'm after and it'd be great if someone could give me the advice. I'm pretty sure I will commit `"src/index.ts"` by an accident one day or even publish a version with this value. The contents of `src/*.ts` are excluded the npm releases to keep my packages small.

Comment: For those who are struggling with the same issue too and want to see a workaround, here's the repo in which I'm applying the hack described above: https://github.com/gicentre/litvis

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/Izhaki/mono.ts

It uses yarn workspaces and marry well with VSCode. I hope the README is clear enough.

Basically, use two (parallel) typescript configuration trees:

- **Pre-build** - uses aliases (for VSCode, tests, webpack, etc).
- **Build** - uses typescript 3 project references for publishing essentially.

Comment: Thanks for you answer @Izhaki! How do you suggest approaching the issue with typings, which I describe in the question? It's the main concern of mine, which I could only overcome by adding those hacky scripts called `use-dev-typings` / `use-prod-typings`.

Comment: Just out: https://github.com/Izhaki/mono.ts; Still need to add README etc, but basically anything tsconfig.json is pre-built (vscode and mocha) and anything tsconfig.build.json is... hmmm... build related.